# Widget Referencing to move a car widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am writing an application which has multiple kv files along with a demo.py file (where the application runs). On one of the .kv files I draw a car using canvas (it is not the main .kv file). I need to write a code to move this car but I do not know how to reference it in the python code.

Also how to refer widgets on different .kv file in another .kv file?

the kv file code is below.
It is basically a MapBox widget on which I want to move cars.

```
<HostCar@Widget>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: 20,35
            source: "host_car.png"
            pos: (700,50)
<MapBox@RelativeLayout>:
    host_car: host_car
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            source: "map_base.jpg"
            size: self.size
            pos: 0,0
        Rectangle:
            pos: 575,412 #light_position
            source: "map_light_grey.png"
            size: 20,20
    HostCar:
        id: host_car
```

How to move the HostCar widget?

Comment: Could you add some of the Python code that is relevant to your question? It's hard to give an answer if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: I am unable to edit my question. Instead I have posted a different question.Thanks.

Comment: @Sarala: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since you have posted a similar question, [Kivy moving a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261420/kivy-moving-a-widget). Please delete this post so that we don't have duplicates. Thank you.